# Server controls event does not work after calling page_clientvalidate() method

Tags: asp.net, javascript

when I call Page_ClientValidate('Add1') function using javascript, the server controls of asp.net event not working .'Add1' is validation group.

Comment: A sample code would totally help!

Answer (score 1):

Please provide some sample code and a better explanation of what you mean by "the server controls of asp.net event not working".

In the meantime, here's some [sample code](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2008/02/13/using-asp-net-validation-from-client-code.aspx) of how `Page_ClientValidate(validationGroup)` should be used:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbHours" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rvalAddHours" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbHours" ValidationGroup="AddEntry" ErrorMessage="* Hours Required" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RangeValidator ID="rgValAddHours" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbHours" ValidationGroup="AddEntry" ErrorMessage="* Hours Must Be 0-24" Display="Dynamic" Type="Double" MinimumValue="0" MaximumValue="24"></asp:RangeValidator>
<asp:Button ID="btnAddEntry" runat="server" OnClientClick="ValidateAndAddNewEntry(); return false;" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="AddEntry" Text="Create" />

<script type="text/javascript>
 function ValidateAndAddNewEntry() {
    var res = Page_ClientValidate("AddEntry");    
    if ( res == true ) {
        //Do work
    }
 }
</script>
```